# Single XML element mapped to multiple Attributes in POJO jaxb

Tags: java, jaxb

I have an XML element like this in version 1.x

```
<virtual_machine>
<Status>
    <state>Running</state>
<Status>
</virtual_machine>
```

The corresponding pojo for the same is as below

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "virtual_machine")
public class virtual_machine
{
    @NotPersistent
    @XmlElement(name = "status")
        private VMStatus              status;
}

@XmlRootElement(name = "status")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class VMStatus 
{
    @XmlElement(name = "state")
    private String state;

    public String getState() {
        return state;
    }

    public void setState(String state) {
        this.state = state;
    }


}
```

It worked fine till the next version got released.

The next version has XML tags changed as below

```
<virtual_machine>
<Status>Running</Status>
</virtual_machine>
```

Now how should i modify the existing POJO to handle both the cases.

Please advice.

Comment: If you have single status only then no need to create another class type,Status. Simply use String object in vitual_machine class.

Comment: The same Pojo should support for both kind of the XML packets ..

Comment: I think this can not be possible, As It can not be possible for java to to determine when you want to use Status as String and when you want to use Status as User defined data type.